# Mac OS X IDE with intelligent code completion and error checking

Tags: osx, ide, c#

I'm looking for an IDE like Visual Studio to develop using especially C#.

**Requirements**

- Must be on Mac OS X
- Must have [intelligent code completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion)
- Must have auto indent
- Must have shortcuts (believe me, this is a requirement for me)
- Must be able to code using **at least** C#, JavaScript, HTML and CSS
- Must have break points
- Must be able to compile

  - Check for errors (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>)
  - Open a browser with the software with the possibility of navigate through the code (*break-points*)<kbd>f5</kbd>

Comment: Hey - this is much later but, ReSharper (you can use more than C#, or you can use IntelliJ, same developer) is an IDE with all of the mentioned features plus customizable shortcuts, a dark theme, open source support, check for errors before compilation, rename variables, navigation with command-click, and code formatting. Seriously, try it. It's really good.

Comment: @CrazyPython you could post it as an answer. I'll check this out when I got home =) thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)** is a cross platform IDE that allows of editing C# and other .NET languages.

It has:

- Mac OS compatibility
- Code Completion
- Auto indent
- User configurable keyboard shortcuts including Emacs and Visual Studio compatible profiles
- Great c# support
- Web Development support.
- Build, Run, Breakpoints, Error List etc.

Please find a per-platform feature matrix [here](http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Feature_List).

[image]

*In my personal opinion MonoDevelop ranks very well in comparison with other IDEs.  While it fails to offer as diverse a range of project types as Visual Studio, for what is does support it does it very well.  It's narrower scope allows it to have a more streamlined interface that some of the busier IDEs like Eclipse*

Answer (score 3):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is a new tool in preview from Microsoft. This Satya Nadella' Microsoft so it runs on Linux, Mac OSX, and Windows. Languages include HTML, CSS, Less, Sass, JSON. ASP.NET V5 and Nodejs. Intellisense. Bracket matching. Git support. regular expression searching in the search box.  Peek Definition. support for multiple cursors. Parameter Hints. Snippets. Reference info. Symbol renaming. Errors and warnings. Side-by-side editing. Yes, and auto indentation.

There is a command palette with keyboard shortcuts for the most common operations. Also shortcut customization.

word completion, plus for the rich languages, such as JavaScript, JSON, HTML, CSS, Less, Sass, C# and TypeScript, Code offers IntelliSense experience. https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/codebasics

JavaScript, TypeScript or C#, parameter hints will pop up as you're typing a method invocation

Built-in debugger with edit, compile and debug.

Breakpoints can be toggled by clicking on the editor margin. Breakpoint management can be done in the debug view. Node debugging. Javascript source maps.

Variables can be inspected in the debug view, or using a hover which only supports simple inspection.

- continue / pause F5
- step over F10
- step into F11
- step out ⇧F11 (Windows, Linux Shift+F11)
- stop ⇧F5 (Windows, Linux Shift+F5)

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/debugging

Make sure that you have installed Mono, and also that Mono is in your PATH.